# After update to rails 5.1 gives error on gem "activemodel"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

After updating to rails 5.1 from 4.2.8 It gives error on running 'bundle update'.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    protected_attributes (~> 1.1.4) was resolved to 1.1.4, which depends on
      activemodel (< 5.0, >= 4.0.1)

    rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
    activemodel (= 5.1.0)

    rails (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
    activemodel (= 5.1.0)
```

It seems that protected_attributes gem doesn't compatible with rails version 5.1. Is there any way to tackle this issue without removing  protected_attributes gem?

Comment: If you go to their github page it says `Note: This plugin will be officially supported until the release of Rails 5.0.`

Comment: If you're talking to me I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 2):

As the project's README states:

> This plugin will be officially supported until the release of Rails 5.0

So either maintain your own fork that keeps compatibility with Rails 5.0 and upwards or bite the bullet and embrace strong parameters.